# binary trees searching inside

Tags: scheme, racket

Can anyone tell me what I need to do here?

```
(define (count-values abst v)
  (cond [(empty? abst) 0]
        [else (+ (cond [(equal? v (bae-fn abst)) 1]
                       (else 0))
                 (count-values .... v)
                 (count-values .... v ))]))
```

I basically need a function that counts the amount of symbols v inside a binary tree

```
(define bae
  (make-bae '+
            (make-bae '* (make-bae '+ 4 1)
                      (make-bae '+ 5 2))
            (make-bae '- 6 3)))
(count-values bae '+) => 3
```

because there are 3 '+ in bae

Comment: Do you know about how to design functions for recursive structures?  Have you read something like: http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_two.html#(part._ch~3adesign-lists) yet?

Comment: Are you following the Design Recipe that your teacher is using to teach you how to design programs?  If not, you should.  The code you've shown so far is pretty much skipping every step in the recipe.  It shows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Post the definition of the tree - I'm guessing `bae` is a struct - don't assume we know your code, post all the relevant information as part of the question
2. Make sure that the code you post works at least in part - for instance, the `(define bae ...)` part won't work even if you provided the definition of `bae`, because of a naming conflict
3. Follow the recipe for traversing a binary tree, I bet it's right in the text book

The general idea for the solution goes like this, without taking a look at the actual implementation of the code you've done so far is the only help I can give you:

1. If the tree is empty, then return 0
2. If the current element's value equals the searched value, add 1; otherwise add 0
3. Either way, add the value to the result of recursively traversing the left and right subtrees

Comment: And we can't even say that hint 1 is helpful without knowing what the data definitions are.  Is it even meaningful to talk about an "empty" tree here?  To the original questioner: you _need_ to explain what the structure of your data is: otherwise, there's no good possibility to write programs that process that data.

Answer (score 0):

If you define your data structure recursively, then a recursive count algorithm will naturally arise:

```
;; Utils
(define (list-ref-at n)
  (lambda (l) (list-ref l n)))
(define (eq-to x)
  (lambda (y) (eq? x y)))

;; Data Type    
(define (make-bae op arg1 arg2)
  `(BAE ,op, arg1, arg2))
(define (bae? thing) 
  (and (list? thing) (eq? 'BAE (car thing)) (= 4 (length thing))))
(define bae-op   (list-ref-at 1))
(define bae-arg1 (list-ref-at 2))
(define bae-arg2 (list-ref-at 3))

;; Walk
(define (bae-walk func bae)  ;; 'pre-ish order'
  (if (not (bae? bae))
      (func bae)
      (begin
        (func (bae-op bae))
        (bae-walk func (bae-arg1 bae))
        (bae-walk func (bae-arg2 bae)))))

;; Count
(define (bae-count-if pred bae)
  (let ((count 0))
    (bae-walk (lambda (x) 
                 (if (pred x) 
                     (set! count (+ 1 count))))
              bae)
     count))

(define (bae-count-if-plus bae)
  (bae-count-if (eq-to '+) bae))

> bae
(BAE + (BAE * (BAE + 4 1) (BAE + 5 2)) (BAE - 6 3))

> (bae-count-if-plus bae)
3

;; Find
(define (bae-find-if pred bae)
  (call/cc (lambda (exit)
             (bae-walk (lambda (x)
                         (if (pred x) (exit #t)))
                       bae)
             #f)))
```